# How to read CSV with extra quotes with R?

Tags: r, csv

I have the CSV file like below:

```
data,key
"VA1,VA2,20140524,,0,0,5969,20140523134902,S7,S1147,140,20140523134902,m/t",4503632376496128
"VA2,VA3,20140711,,0,0,8824,20140601095714,S1,S6402,175,20140601095839,m/t",4503643113914368
```

I try to read it with R, but I don't need `key` value and `data` value should be read to separate columns. With the following code I get almost what I need:

```
data <- read.csv(fileCSV, header = FALSE, sep = ",", skip = 1, comment.char = "", quote = "")
```

I skip header line there (`skip = 1`), say that I don't have it (`header = FALSE`), and say that I don't have quotes (`quote = ""`). But in result I get quote characters in V1 and V13 columns and extra V14 column:

```
     V1  V2       V3 V4 V5 V6   V7           V8 V9   V10 V11          V12  V13          V14
1  "VA1 VA2 20140524 NA  0  0 5969 2.014121e+13 S7 S1147 140 2.014121e+13 m/t" 4.503608e+15
```

Should I delete it somehow after reading csv? Or, is there any better way to read such csv files?

**Upd**. I use the following approach to delete quotes:

```
data[,"V1"] = sub("^\"", "", data[,"V1"])
data[,"V13"] = sub("\"$", "", data[,"V13"])
```

But `factor` type is changed to `character` for these columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a system command with `fread()`?

```
writeLines(
'data,key 
"VA1,VA2,20140524,,0,0,5969,20140523134902,S7,S1147,140,20140523134902,m/t",4503632376496128
"VA2,VA3,20140711,,0,0,8824,20140601095714,S1,S6402,175,20140601095839,m/t",4503643113914368', "x.txt"
)

require(bit64)
data.table::fread("cat x.txt | rev | cut -d '\"' -f2 | rev | tail -n +2")
#     V1  V2       V3 V4 V5 V6   V7             V8 V9   V10 V11            V12 V13
# 1: VA1 VA2 20140524 NA  0  0 5969 20140523134902 S7 S1147 140 20140523134902 m/t
# 2: VA2 VA3 20140711 NA  0  0 8824 20140601095714 S1 S6402 175 20140601095839 m/t
```

Here's a test on the two methods, as requested.

```
## 150k lines
writeLines(c("data,key\n", rep_len(
'"VA1,VA2,20140524,,0,0,5969,20140523134902,S7,S1147,140,20140523134902,m/t",4503632376496128\n', 1.5e5)),
     "test.txt"
)

## fread() in well under 1 second (with bit64 loaded)
system.time({
    dt <- data.table::fread(
        "cat test.txt | rev | cut -d '\"' -f2 | rev | grep -e '^V'"
    )
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.945   0.108   0.547 

## your current read.csv() method in just over two seconds
system.time({
    df <- read.csv("test.txt", header = FALSE, sep = ",", skip = 1, comment.char = "", quote = "")
    df[,"V1"] = sub("^\"", "", df[,"V1"])
    df[,"V13"] = sub("\"$", "", df[,"V13"])
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  2.134   0.000   2.129 

dim(dt)
# [1] 150000     13
dim(df)
# [1] 150000     14
```

Comment: Thanks. Will it be more effective than what I do now - `read.csv` without last column (`colClasses = c(..., "NULL")`) and `data[,"V1"] = factor(sub("^\"", "", data[,"V1"]))`?

Comment: I improved my previous answer a little.  Should be much better now

Comment: Will it be faster than what I do? How to compare performance? The actual file has around 177'000 records and I have several files...

Comment: I imagine it will be a lot faster, but I'll go test it

Comment: @LA_ - data.table is about 3.5 times faster in my example but I don't think your code removed the 14th column

Comment: Thanks a lot! My code removes last column, yours doesn't since you haven't added `colClasses` with last `NULL` value to `read.csv`.